# extraer dato en especifico de xml?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, script

buen dia

El script que tengo el me imprime todos los datos que esten en `<data>`, pero necesito que me imprima uno en especifico:

este es el xml

control92.500.40

```css
<DATABASE><basedatos>control</basedatos><data>92.50</data><log>0.40</log></DATABASE><DATABASE><basedatos>db_medios</basedatos><data>22.30</data><log>0.40</log></DATABASE><DATABASE><basedatos>generales</basedatos><data>96.80</data><log>2.80</log></DATABASE>
```

es decir que solo me imprima el dato de `<data> de la base de datos "generales"`
este el script que con ayuda de esta comunidad construi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#doc = minidom.parse("/home/eavacca/Documents/SE_SAPASE2.xml")
#data = doc.getElementsByTagName("data")
#for elemento in data:
#nombre = elemento.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("basedatos") 
[0].firstChild.data
valor = float(elemento.firstChild.data)
#print(int(float("{}".format( valor))))
```

hace dias recibi colaboración a traves de este medio pero necesito ayuda nuevamente ya que estoy iniciando en este tema de script´s

gracias..

Comment: he modificado el codigo y puse algo asi :
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('/home/eavacca/Documents/SE_SAPASE2.xml')
data = tree.findall('.//basedatos/control/data')
for elemento in data:
    print(data.text)
pero al ejecutarlo no me sale error pero no imprime tampoco nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No programo en Phyton, pero tu problema debe estar en la expresión XPath que le pasas a `tree.findall`

Según la estructura del documento que tienes, posiblemente la expresión correcta es

```
tree.findall('DATABASE[basedatos="control"]/data')
```

Comment: gracias llevaba tres dias con este tema , pero veo que tu aporte es bastante bueno  Gracias